# How do I insert a value into a URL?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have the following code where I try to insert `randomValue` into an URL.

```
int randomValue = qrand() % 100;
view = new QWebView(this) ;

view->load(QUrl("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?q=C&start="+randomValue+"&num=1&output=rss"));
```

The following error is reported:

> error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [18]' to binary 'operator+'

So, I want to append the `randomValue` into the URL. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **QString** for this. It is far more capable than std::string and it provides what you need directly.

```
QString baseurl("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?q=C&num=1&output=rss&start=%1");
view->load(QUrl(baseurl.arg(randomValue)));
```

See [QString documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qstring.html#arg-10) for more details.

Comment: Yep, I love the qt-way of passing arguments to strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sprintf` function. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) for example.

Another option would be to use `std::string` or even `std::ostringstream` . Depends on what you prefer (and I do not know what kind of params can QUrl take).

```
char mytext[ 256 ]; // make sure the buffer is large enough!
int randomValue = 12345;
sprintf( "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?q=C&start=%d&num=1&output=rss", randomValue );
```

Notice the **%d** where you want your value. This makes `sprintf` to replace it with the value of `randomValue`, passes as a second parameter. For more info, please see the reference link above.

**NOTE:** you might consider to do it the Qt way as described in another answer.

Comment: I print the variable randomValue but how to append into the url code, I mean I use + operator to append but it was not accepted. so which operator accepted?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `operator +` for `char*`. You should either use C++-style `std::string`, or qt-specific `QString`, both of them support `operator +`.

Actually, `QString` is a good idea, because `QUrl` accepts it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use stringstream to build the string

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?q=C&start=" << randomValue << "&num=1&output=rss";
view->load(QUrl(oss.str()));

Answer (score 0):

use

```
... + QString::number( randomValue ) + ...
```

and it should work.

Neither C++ (nor QString) implicitely convert numbers to strings.